# Conductive ink on silicon to bridge two isolated regions of the wafer

Tags: experimental-chemistry, metal, semiconductors

Can I use a thin layer of conductive ink on silicon to bridge two isolated regions of the wafer (p-type)? I know that using PVD methods would be the best option, but I don't have access to these expensive tools. How would these conventional conductive inks adhere to silicon? Or would silicon be "inkphobic"?

Comment: What is the **scale** of the device, and what is the allowable **circuit resistance** in your use? Most conductive inks are made of metal particles in a non-conductive binder. Given a large enough trace width and thickness, enough metal particles contact each other to complete a circuit. A thin trace would likely have high resistance.

Comment: This is a really interesting question! Local interconnects on silicon (as opposed to going up into the metal layers and then back down again) come and go in VLSI design. For "inkaphobicity" note that absolutely clean silicon (which doesn't last long in air) is not particularly hydrophilic, but it quickly grows a native oxide layer in air; once you get monolayer or two of SiO2 on top it's just as hydrophilic as glass. You can delay that by passivating the dangling Si bonds on the surface with things like fluorine or hydrogen (the "HF dip" step)

Comment: Also, since silicon is a semiconductor and not a metal, it is a challenge to make good electrical contact with the conduction band. You need to think about how to make an [ohmic contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmic_contact) between each end of the ink path and the semiconductor. Using very highly doped silicon helps, but only on one end or the other. Thus for a given direction of current flow you'd need a heavily p-doped silicon pad under one end and heavily n-doped silicon pad under the other.

Comment: potentially helpful would be some reading on [printed electronics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_electronics)